# Filter Data block with a LOV value in Oracle Forms 10g

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, lov

I need to implement a simple product form from a block of data called "**PRODUCTS**".

The products are related to a "Partner" through the field "**COMPANIES_PARTNERS_ID**".

This field will be represented by an **LOV** to select the Partner for which we want to visualize your products.

If there is not a partner currently selected, all your products should be displayed. And when a partner is selected, only their products should be displayed.

**The form will look like this:**

[image: oracle forms]

The button to the right of the search field should show the LOV and launch the query. I tried the following code as a **"Smart Trigger"** when I pressed the button. But it does not work well at all. The LOV list appears twice and when no partner is selected, no product appears.

[image]

Could someone help me to implement this functionality? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You don't need to use `ENTER_QUERY` command.
- had better using `DEFAULT_WHERE` set with respect to `COMPANIES_PARTNERS_ID`. If not selected any of the rows of LOV by pressing `CANCEL` or dissmissing by `X` sign, then all of the products will be listed(In this case you'll see the first ID, most probably with value `1`, since `COMPANIES_PARTNERS_ID` is not located at a `CONTROL` block but at the same block,namely `PRODUCTS`, with other items. As you go down by down-arrow you'll see the other `ID` values when your cursor is in `COMPANIES_PARTNERS_ID` field, seems that Number Of Items Displayed is set to `1` for this field, because `PRODUCTS` block has been set as `10` items displayed ).

So, you may use the following code in `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` trigger :

```
DECLARE
    V_WHERE VARCHAR2(500);
BEGIN   
    GO_ITEM('COMPANIES_PARTNERS_ID');
  IF SHOW_LOV('COMPANIES_LOV') THEN
    V_WHERE:='COMPANIES_PARTNERS_ID='||:COMPANIES_PARTNERS_ID;
  ELSE  
    V_WHERE:='1=1';           
  END IF;           
    SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY('PRODUCTS',DEFAULT_WHERE,V_WHERE);
    CLEAR_BLOCK(NO_VALIDATE);   
    EXECUTE_QUERY;  
END;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. The solution is great.

Comment: @AbdullahBahattab you're welcome bro. You could try to upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Once you enter query mode (which is what `ENTER_QUERY` does), further processing is stopped until you execute query.

I presume that you created a LoV properly - the most usual way is to create a Record Group query first, and then create a LoV based on it.

Therefore, I'd `ENTER_QUERY` in `WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE` trigger and let your current push button display LoV and let user select a value into the "Companies Partners ID" item. Executing a query (either by pressing the corresponding toolbar button, shortcut key (F8?) or your new "Execute query" button) would then actually *execute query*. If master-detail relationship is properly created (using the Data Block wizard is the simplest option), then you'd get rows in the "Products" block.

Answer (score 1):

Put a value in PRODUCTS block WHERE clause' property.

WHERE CLAUSE property:

```
COMPANIES_PARTNERS_ID LIKE NVL(:lov_block.COMPANIES_PARTNERS_ID, '%')
```